# Difference between Springboot 1.X and Springboot 2.0

Tags: spring-boot

We have been using Springboot 1.X for our applications.
Now were are getting ready to start on a few new applications and was wondering if we should go with SpringBoot2.0 or stick with SpringBoot 1.X?

Any thoughts on one version or the other?

Also, what are the differences between Spring Boot 1.X vs Spring Boot 2.0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can find differences and migration guide here :
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide

- Java 8 is base version
- properties changed
- spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=true  is default value
- Spring Security configuration become easier
- Spring Security Oauth2 merges into Spring Security
- Better dependency management

Answer (score 23):

SpringBoot 2.* Changes:

1.**Java 8** is minimum version

2.**Tomcat** version **8.5** is minimum

3.**Hibernate** version **5.2** is minimum

4.**Gradle** version **3.4** is minimum

5.Added SpringBoot Starters for **WebFlux** and reactive support for **Cassandra**, **MongoDB** and **Redis**.

6.**AutoConfiguration**

a.**Security** (Need to add a bean to expose actuator endpoints like health etc)

**Sample Code:** (Modify  below code based on your needs)

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
     web
        .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/**");
     }
  }
```

b.Need to add **spring-boot-starter-security** dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

7. Actuator Endpoint change:

   **Before 2.***: http://localhost:8080/business-customer/profile**/env** will give the 
   details.

   **From 2.***: http://localhost:8080/business-customer/profile**/actuator/env** will 
   give the details.
8. **Endpoint properties** in **application.properties** (to enable all endpoints)

   management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
   management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=loggers
9. **Connection Pool** by default:

   Before 2.*: tomcat CP

   After 2.*: **HikariCP** (from SpringBoot 2.* You don't need to add HikariCP 
               dependency and its config bean creation and its properties 
               changes.)
10. **Migration**:
    https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/12/upgrading-start-spring-io-to-spring-boot-2

Answer (score 1):

most of the things are getting autoconfigured in 2x from component Scan to auto table creation to the db connected

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this: https://www.baeldung.com/new-spring-boot-2

1. Spring Boot 2.x is the first version to support Java 9.
2. In 2.x by default, everything is secured, including static resources and Actuator endpoints.
3. In Spring Boot 1.x only Spring-MVC was supported for actuator endpoints. In 2.x, however, it became independent and pluggable.
4. In 2.x when our application gets restarted by devtools a ‘delta' report will be printed out.
5. Tomcat minimum supported version is 8.5
6. Hibernate minimum supported version is 5.2
7. Gradle minimum supported version is 3.4