# Is the project bootspring v1 or v2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am a devops engineer currently containerizing java applications for our backend team.

All projects are built with spring-boot and use either spring-boot v2 or (since they're older and more legacy) spring-boot v1.

I have built a spring-boot base image for them to run on and do some additional stuff based on the spring-boot version used.

Sadly for one of the projects I don't have any information if it's v1 or v2. Having no experience with neither java coding nor spring-boot I am at a loss at how to find out.

So the question is: Assuming the source code is present, how can I tell if a project is using spring-boot v2 or v1?

Thanks for your help java gurus!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned *assuming you have source code*, Check for the versions in the pom.xml file.

1. Check for `spring-boot-starter-parent` dependency version to be 2.0.0 or higher and,
2. check the `spring framework` version downloaded to be 5

**Edit:**
If you can run the application, you can also check version with the ascii art that printed out, assuming no customization made:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.3.RELEASE)
```

**Refer:**
1. [Difference between Springboot 1.X and Springboot 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204882/difference-between-springboot-1-x-and-springboot-2-0)
2. https://content.pivotal.io/springone-platform-2017/whats-new-in-spring-boot-2-0-phillip-webb-madhura-bhave

Comment: Grand, precisely what I needed. Thank you sir! `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId><version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>` So this one is spring-boot v1.